# Is there any application out there to visualize data flow between tables and databases in a Django application in real time?

Tags: python, database, django, orm, data-visualization

The first step is [done](http://code.google.com/p/django-graphviz/) - a simple relational model of all tables (and hopefully their fields) in the given databases. The next step I haven't found done anywhere after some basic googling - a graphical display that shows (maybe with a pulse of color) access to a given table's fields in a given database as it happens, maybe drawing arrows to point out joins.

Obviously this is more about demonstration than analysis. But I think it could be a fun (and interesting, and just maybe a little useful) toy.

Is there such a thing out there? If not, does anyone want to collaborate on it with me?

Answer (score 1):

If you are about to implement it yourself, you should start with writing a wrapper to the original django.db.models.Model' s default manager and log access, or use signals to communicate with a visualizer app.

Comment: I think the graphics part will be a lot harder than the wrapper - I'm pretty well acquainted with the django ORM at this point. But yes, lots of work.